# SQL Remove Characters from delimeted string

Tags: sql

I have a string in the following format. Im trying to create a one-off function in SQL to remove certain charcters.

Sample String:

```
Var s = '18160 ~ SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | 18170 ~ SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | 18180 ~ SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~ | 18190 ~ SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~'
```

Desired Result:

```
s = 'SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~
   |SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~'
```

If you notice above the ID'S for instance 18160, 18170, 18180 and 18190 were removed. This is just as example. the structure is as follows:

```
id: 18160
description : SCC-Hard Drive
Type: 4
comment: d
```

So where there are multiple items they get concatenated using the Pike delimeter. So my requirement is to remove the id's from a given string in the above structure.

In Javascript I know I could use a regex and do the following and it works, just need to do  it in SQL 08

```
s.replace(/\d{5}\s~\s/g, "")
```

Comment: Is the id always the first field in the string?

Comment: @clav Yes, Id is always the first field in the string

Comment: Are there always four elements in the string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There could be n number of elements in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using `CHARINDEX` for this if I have to do it in SQL. I try to avoid using SQL for this sort of string manipulation if I can help it, though.

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(2500), @result VARCHAR(2500), @tilde INT, @pipe INT, @length INT, @calc INT
SELECT @s = '18160 ~ SCC-Hard Drive ~ 4 ~ d | 18170 ~ SCC-SSD ~ 4 ~ de | 18180 ~ SCC-Monitor ~ 5 ~ | 18190 ~ SCC-Keyboard ~ null ~'
SELECT @length = LEN(@s)
SELECT @tilde = PATINDEX('% ~%', @s);
SELECT @pipe =  PATINDEX('% | %', @s);

--If there's no tilde, then there's only one element
IF (@tilde = 0 OR @length = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @s; 
    RETURN;
END 
--If no pipe, there's only one set
ELSE IF @pipe = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(@s, SUBSTRING(@s, 0, @tilde +3), '')
    RETURN;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --clear first id
    SELECT @s = REPLACE(@s, SUBSTRING(@s, 0, @tilde +3), '')
    SELECT @pipe = CHARINDEX('|', @s)
    SELECT @tilde = CHARINDEX('~', @s, @pipe +1);
    WHILE @pipe > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @calc = (@tilde - @pipe)     
        SELECT @s = REPLACE(@s, SUBSTRING(@s, @pipe + 1, @calc), '')
        SELECT @pipe = CHARINDEX('|', @s, @pipe +1)
        SELECT @tilde = CHARINDEX('~', @s, @pipe +1);
    END
    SELECT @s
END
```

Comment: The column comes from a table called PartDescription, Im sorry I did not specify that before. However when I try to select that column from the table by the using the following SELECT @s = (select partdescription from serviceentry where PartDescription is not null)  would you know what i would need to change from your query

Comment: You can only do one row at a time that way, so if you're wanting to do it for each row in a table using this solution, you'd have to loop through each row one at a time, unfortunately. Also, would be good to note that this is only going to work in SQL Server for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a single expression but it should be quite simple to create a function that loops until the record separators, |, are exhausted. For each match, locate the first ~. Concatenate parts of the string along the loop. You need to use functions  locate, substring, and concat, which are common in DBMSes. I'm not sure what exactly is your problem, but regular expressions are not standard and at least in mySQL you can't use them for replacement.